# I want to change the resolution to 1600x900

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, hardware

Hola tengo recién instalado Ubuntu 15.04 y una placa de video nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430, de 32 bits y una frecuencia de 60 Hz. Quisiera cambiar la resolucion de 1024x768 a 1600x900, pero no me aparece esa opcion en la configuracion del monitor. Gracias

Translation:
Hi, I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 and I have an NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 card that I would like to use. The problem is that I can only set my resolution to 1024x768 and not my monitor's resolution, which is 1600x900. How can I fix this?

Comment: Creo que tienes que hablar en ingles. Usas translate.google.com si no puedes hablar ingles.

Comment: Search `additional drivers` in Unity Dash and use that to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers for Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry am new to this

Comment: It's fine, just delete your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to **system settings** then **software and updates**.
- In software and updates, you will get to see **additional driver**
  option.
- You can search it from here. Select appropriate driver and apply
  changes.

If this is not work you can install it from command line.

---

You can install NVIDIA driver with command line:

**Install/Upgrade to NVIDIA 340.65 in Ubuntu 15.04 / 14.10 / 14.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

If this is not work then try this

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

(open a terminal with F1)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo service lightdm start
```

For more information check this [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-nvidia-340-65-ubuntu-1504/)